# Arch on WSL: libQt5Core.so.5 not found, despite being installed

Tags: linux, windows-10, arch-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qt

I was hit by some hardcore power-tripping forum mods on the Arch Linux forum, so here I am.

I'm trying to run GUI apps on WSL, such as dolphin or kate. However, none of them can find `libQt5Core.so.5`, despite it being installed in `/usr/lib` as you'd expect. Here's a terminal transcript:

```sh
/u/lib » DISPLAY=:0.0 dolphin
dolphin: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/u/lib » pwd
/usr/lib
/u/lib » ls -la | grep Qt5Core
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1143 Aug  7 06:05 libQt5Core.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug  7 06:05 libQt5Core.so -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug  7 06:05 libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.1*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Aug  7 06:05 libQt5Core.so.5.11 -> libQt5Core.so.5.11.1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5234312 Aug  7 06:05 libQt5Core.so.5.11.1*
/u/lib » ldd `which dolphin`
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffdb426000)
...
        libQt5Core.so.5 => not found
/u/lib » pacman -Qk qt5-base
qt5-base: 3546 total files, 0 missing files
```

Note that other GUI apps work fine - anything compiled against GTK, including Firefox, work perfectly. I just have to set the `$DISPLAY` variable. Not setting the var doesn't help, as you'd expect.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You were NOT hit by power-tripping on the Arch forums.  I saw your post there, your post was dust-binned because Arch on WSL is NOT the official Arch.  If they allowed every kind of derivative of Arch then the forum and Wiki would be useless because of all the special instructions for each flavor.  If you want official support on the Arch forums then run ARCH.  Period.

Comment: I was just hoping for some *community* help with diagnosing my issue, and ruling out non-kernel issues. It's not like I was calling the support line of a commercial product which I was using against the TOS or something.

Comment: [That’s probably what you’re running into](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232682).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found a fix: https://github.com/kdudka/csmock/commit/96a4a759a7de39f8da109202f4fa14c76a0ae68f

Or simply run:

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5
```

The root cause does seem to be related to the lack of `renameat2()` in the WSL 'kernel'.

More information: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3023

Thanks to Daniel B for the nudge to get me started on this!

Comment: For some reason, my QT libraries were in a different location, so I needed to run: `sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5`

Comment: @bart The reason must be that you are not running Arch Linux. Probably Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: @ypnos you're right, that'll be the reason. Nonetheless, this answer solved the problem on Debian as well - with the path modification.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following steps :

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install qt5ct
```

then i lauch VcXSrv and problem pass

I don not know which step solved the problem though
My issue came from launching gnuplot.