# wireshark: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5

Tags: linux, wireshark, qt

I succesfully installed wireshark `2.6.2`, but I can't execute it due to this error

> wireshark: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked for the library and it is present in my system in
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5` but if i do `ldd /usr/bin/wireshark` i have this output

> ...
>   libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
>   (0x00007f2764ec6000)
>   **libQt5Core.so.5 => not found**
>   ...

I have no idea how to tell wireshark to read the library in the correct path.
Does anyone could help me ?

Comment: Something similar with https://superuser.com/questions/1347723

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1347723/arch-on-wsl-libqt5core-so-5-not-found-despite-being-installed) and to @Biswapriyo

I succesfully solved my issue by this command

> sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5